# import Google Cloud Talent Solution for Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-talent-solution

I've succeeded in making updates to a Datastore.
And then I've followed [Google's instructions](https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/docs/before-you-begin#client-libraries-install-python) to use Google Cloud Talent Solution.

But this line fails when I run one of my functions:

```
from google.cloud import talent_v4beta1
```

While MS Code offers to complete the library `talent_v4beta1` when I run the code locally, it crashes at the above line reporting:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'talent_v4beta1' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
```

In the doc page (linked above) it suggests

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud
```

but this, perhaps installs an older library? It reports "google-cloud-0.34.0". My `Google Cloud SDK` reports `250.0.0`. Does the latter use the former?

When I CMD `pip install --upgrade google-cloud` it reports:

```
Collecting google-cloud
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/b1/7c54d1950e7808df06642274e677dbcedba57f75307adf2e5ad8d39e5e0e/google_cloud-0.34.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: google-cloud
Successfully installed google-cloud-0.34.0
```

Can you see what step I've missed or tripped over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install also the library google-cloud-talent

```
pip3 install google-cloud-talent
```

Comment: Do you have a Google web page for reference? I searched for such an instruction without success.

Comment: Nope. It seems that is slightly outdated for python. I found it out browsing the github  repo linked in the webpage. They have more examples there.

Comment: Documentation is certainly one area where Google's platform costs one a lot of time. Thanks for github repo tip. (Keeping one's Python 2 and Python 3 installation straight is also very important to getting Google Cloud to work.)